# Is there a way to determine if photo was taken at sunrise or sunset?

Tags: landscape, sunlight, sun, sunset, sunrise

When I look at photos of sunrise respectively sunset and do **not** know the cardinal direction I'm not able to identify if this photo was taken on sunrise or sunset. So I ask myself the question is there a way to determine? Maybe color temperature of sky, color of the sun or something like this (consider photo no color shifts by post processing).

Comment: With a digital image, EXIF timestamp would be my first thing to look for.

Comment: @Philip Kendall: Yes it a duplicate - you are right. Didn't found this question while searching :-/ Thanks for hint.

Comment: No problem - it'll probably get closed as a duplicate in a while, although I think this is actually close enough that a mod could merge the two questions entirely.

Comment: You can often see this when a film is shot at dawn, but the scene is supposed to be taking place at dusk (dawn lasts longer making it easier to get the shot right right in one day.) There *tends* to be a cooler, blue tint to the sky at dawn and a warmer, red tint at dusk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed difficult, if not impossible, to tell at times. Here's a list a strategies I might use to tell the difference:

- Look for contextual clues. Even a tiny recognizable feature could reveal the cardinal direction.
- Atmospheric clarity. During a sunrise, the dust has had time to settle at night, making the sky clearer than at sunset, where there is a lot of particulate matter. You might be able to find minute differences in this and, combined with other factors, make a determination.
- Tilt of the Earth. This requires that you have at least two photos from the same sequence but with enough time in between that the sun has had a chance to move significantly. In the northern hemisphere, the sun rises up and toward the right, while it sets down and toward the right (which is the opposite since if you interpreted this as a sunrise, the sun would appear to rise up and toward the left). The reverse is true for the southern hemisphere. This requires knowing which hemisphere you're in, and ideally far away from the Tropics of Cancer and Capricorn.

Source: http://www.livescience.com/34065-sunrise-sunset.html

Comment: Thanks so far for interesting facts and the link. Indeed helpful. +1 for that.

Comment: "Enough time" might be less than you think. In a lot of hdr scenarios, even a minute is already so much that I can notice the misalignment of the sun, when shooting with tripod and enough zoom.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, if there is a body of water in the picture, it would be more still during sunrise than sunset because the cooler temperatures of the night results in less wind.

From Scott Kelby's, The Digital Photography Book (the first)

> Another advantage of shooting at dawn (rather than at sunset) is that
>   water (in ponds, lakes, bays, etc.) is more still at dawn because
>   there’s usually less wind in the morning than in the late afternoon.
>   So, if you’re looking for that glassy mirror-like reflection in the
>   lake, you’ve got a much better shot at getting that effect at dawn
>   than you do at dusk.

Comment: But how can you tell from a photo if it's "more still" than in some other photo which you don't have? And the wind may have died down during the day anyway...

Comment: @PhilipKendall - of course you cannot say anything for sure. But a completely still body of water can indicate that there is a _probability_ that it is taken at dawn.

Comment: I added a quote from Scott Kelby which I think is probably my own source of this piece of information.